# Building queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build queries dynamically, but I'm having difficulties in their efficiency.

Lets say i have this form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]">

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_2[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_2[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_2[]">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function add_item_to_query($query)
{

    $item_array = [];
    if(isset($_POST["item"])){
        $query .= " AND ";
        foreach ($_POST["item"] as $item){
            $item_array[] = "item LIKE '%$item%'";
        }
        $query .= implode(' OR ',$item_array);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I am using this code to dynamically create a query, however, when the user does not select any checkbox, an error occurs (memory limit) in the construction of the same... how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in that code that would trigger a memory error with no items selected, so would it be right to assume you mean the memory error occurs when you execute the query?

If that's the case it will most likely be a result of the base query not having an WHERE clauses and thus returning the entire, presumedly large, data set.

Comment: yes, the dataset is big... how can a void the memory limit error?

Comment: easiest option - just add a limit to the query